# Search parallel index

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to allow the user to input the index number then print the index value like if the user inputs 0 it will print the 0 index value from both lists, names and grades, so it would print "Jake" and "100" I can't figure out how to do this so here is my code so far ^-^

```
names = ["James", "Jake", "John"]
grades = [100, 30, 64]

answer = ""
while answer != "quit":
    answer = int(input("What student ID would you like to view"))
```

Comment: You have a typo "amswer"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I misread your question.  I thought you wanted to look things up in one list.  If all you want is an index, then that should be obvious.

And I've changed your loop so it is possible to type "quit".

```
names = ["James", "Jake", "John"]
grades = [100, 30, 64]

while True:
    answer = input("What student ID would you like to view? ")
    if answer == "quit":
        break
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer >= len(names):
        print( "Number is out of bounds." )
        continue
    print(names[answer], grades[answer])
```

Comment: the while answer part is for the while loop. you most likely already figured that out

Comment: Also is it possible to have an if statement to check if the value entered is a certain index number to print that value? Like if the number is 1 then print index 1

Comment: I know what the while loop is for, but it won't work.  `answer` can NEVER be "quit", because if you type "quit", you will get an exception.  Try it.